# Headline format differs in preview from published

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

On SO I was just editing an answer when I noticed this.

In the preview the headline appears large & bold:

[image]

but in the published version it is just followed by an HR:

[image: in]

I was editing https://stackoverflow.com/a/63357424/3195477 if it matters.

Comment: It’s not “underlined”. It’s a simple paragraph without special formatting, followed by a horizontal rule. It’s a bug, nonetheless, since that is valid Markdown formatting for a heading.